# How to remove "where from" xattr data from image files downloaded in Mac?

Tags: mojave, google-chrome, metadata, image-processing

Hi so I'm at my wits end coz I am trying to remove xattr data in an image file that is a "Where from" xattr data. This is on a Mojave mac.

This data is written via chrome browser for mac whenever an image is downloaded via this browser.

So I tried this command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms test.jpg
```

but it shows the following result:

```
xattr: test.jpg: No such xattr: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
```

How do I remove this data from the image file then? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That `xattr` _command_ works for me. BTW You either need to change directory `cd ...` to, or use the full path to the target _file_.  Also, that _error message_ is appropriate if the target file does not have that _extended attribute_ set.

Comment: Show us that that file with those extended-attributes does exist at that pathname: `ls -l@ /path/to/filename`. Best to use absolute paths, not `test.jpg`, it might be picking up some other `test.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

Your command works for me, even copying it and supplying an appropriate filename. As suggested in the comments, you need to ensure that the correct filepath is being supplied, and that the file has the attribute to start with.

You can see whether the file has the attribute in a number of ways:

```
ls -l@ /path/to/filename
```

Or:

```
xattr /path/to/filename
```

Comment: So thanks, I tried your ls command and here is the result on a test.jpg file:  com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags    42
 com.apple.quarantine    57

Comment: @sd100 So it looks like that file doesn't have 'WhereFroms' metadata. You should also be able to check in Get Info in the Finder: the URL of where the file was downloaded will be shown there. If it doesn't have one, then there is no such data!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a genuine problem here, not one merely caused by a missing or incorrect path.

As far as I can tell google drive prevents xattrs from being deleted in files which are synced *from* the cloud (i.e. files in the virtual drives which gdrive creates to store local copies of cloud files).

An ugly workaround is to move the file to some folder which is not being synced with gdrive (often ones desktop is not synced) and use xattr -d to delete the unwanted attributes there. Once deleted you can move the file to where you like.

It is truly odd that one can create and alter xattrs but not delete them, when they are being managed by gdrive. Very unexpected behaviour.